# I've defined a function for a string to be written, and then each individual letter to be printed out. But it won't work with an input()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get it to print the question out, letter by letter, all in the same line.

```
import sys
import time

def typing(msg):
    for z in msg:
        time.sleep(0.04)
        sys.stdout.write(z)
        sys.stdout.flush()

input(typing('What is your name?  '))
```

output:
`What is your name?None`

Comment: The requirement is very ambiguous. IT's better to have output to confirm it.

Comment: thanks for the updates. Next time, you could put ###Updates on the first line to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of input and typing:

```
import sys
import time

def typing(msg):
    for z in msg:
        time.sleep(0.04)
        sys.stdout.write(z)
        sys.stdout.flush()

typing(input())
```

Comment: Now you can type something, press enter and it will print it.

Comment: This solution will not meet the req. `a string to be written, and each letter`? or should say - it just print each letter rapidly -0.04 sec.

Comment: Actually, I wanted it to use typing() on the question.                                                                    for example,                                                                                                                                 ```   input('Enter you name:  ')    ```                                                                                                                                            and then have that string, printing every character individually, on the same line.              Sorry if I didn't explain the problem properly.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding op. His function was not working with input, now it does, right?

Comment: Once the req. is clear the solution will make sense then. Both deserve the points - based on the original/updated clarification  PO info. And the way he/you want to approach the problem is not very good/encouraged.  Know why?

Comment: I wouldn't like the user's input to be the one that's being printed out, just for the question that's being asked to be printed out letter by letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You don't need `sys` module, I believe.

```
import time


def typing(msg):
    print(msg)
    
    for ch in msg:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(ch)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        



message = input('Whatever a message you want here: ')

typing(message)
```

Action & Output:

```
Whatever a message you want here: Python is great
Python is great
P
y
t
h
o
n
 
i
s
 
g
r
e
a
t
>>>
```

Comment: I just needed the import sys, so that it would all print out in one line.